# Regular Expression to exclude emailids with special characters

Tags: regex

I have a sample set of emailids below

```
EmailAddress
abc@in.in
#abc@in.in
abc@in.in&
a#b#c@in.in
a!bc@in.in
a$bc@in.in
a+bc@in.+in
ab-c-@in.in
ab/c\@in.in
ab\c@in.in
ab~~~~c@in.in
una02@gmail.com
```

I have to separate invalid mailids containing special characters other than `- _ @ .`
I wrote below rex and its working fine. Please point out if I missed any possible scenario or this rex can be improved. Thanks in advance.

```
[^\$\+\\/~#!&]*

Clean List
abc@in.in
ab-c-@in.in
una02@gmail.com

Invalid List
#abc@in.in
abc@in.in&
a#b#c@in.in
a!bc@in.in
a$bc@in.in
a+bc@in.+in
ab/c\@in.in
ab\c@in.in
ab~~~~c@in.in
```

Comment: This is one of the intermediate step. There are other steps like to check if it fits abc@abc.abc format or not completely numerical etc.

Comment: Please use SO for asking about programming problems. This is a code review problem where you ask for potential problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eleminated the addresses with the # in the local-part.
I think after RFC 5322 is is a valid character.